# Show count comments under the title

Tags: comments

i want to show how many comments has each post in the home page.

Searching the wordpress guide i found this code

```
<p>
  This post currently has
  <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>.
</p>
```

Where i have to put in? 
I use Twentyy Seventeen template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should look at [creating a child theme](https://make.wordpress.org/training/handbook/theme-school/child-themes/child-themes-twentyseventeen/). That way, any modifications you make won't be removed by a Wordpress update.

Next, edit wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content.php and look for the following code:

```
        if ( is_single() ) {
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        } elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
                the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' );
        } else {
                the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        }
```

After that, simply add the following:

```
// Show number of comments
echo '<div>(' . comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ) . ')</div>';
```

This should show an output of
**Your Page Title**
(13 responses)